# Error when parsing array with OpenLayers and Protocol.HTTP()

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, openlayers

I'm trying to send a JSON file to my Node.js app via Protocol.HTTP. The file is correctly sent, but I can't access to an array. Here is the relevant code :

Client side

```
(...)
    var vectorProtocol = new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
                    url: '/getcoords',
                    format: vectorFormat,
                    readWithPOST: true,
                    params: {
                        "code_company": "8501",
                        "data_company": [
                            {
                                "origin": "2013P00109",
                                "type": "LJ",
                                "naf": "5610A",
                            },
                            {
                                "origin": "2013P00110",
                                "type": "FJ",
                                "naf": "5481"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                });
(...)
```

Server side, I try to build an array with only the "origin" field of my array "data_company":

```
function getCoords(params, callback) {
      var arrOrigin = params.data_company.map(function(d) {
         return d.origin;
      });
      (...)
}
```

And I get this error :

> TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method "map"

It seems that my "data_company" is not recognized as an array but as an object. I tried to JSON.parse(params) before but I get another error :

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token o

Anyway, I'm stuck. Do you have any clue to help me to solve this ?

Thanks

Comment: For what is is worth, your JSON is invalid, as you have an extra comma after  "naf": "5610A", though I doubt this is your problem. JSON is an object, not an array, so JSON.parse is correct, although once parses, you will have an array of data_company. Nodejs does not have a map function. I am not sure which of these is your issue, but I don't think it is an OpenLayers problem.

Comment: @John Barça
Thank you for your answer. I removed the extra comma, but I still have the parsing error.
Node.js JS engine implements Array#map, I used it several times before. I also think it's not an OpenLayers issue.

Comment: Suggest you add a nodejs tag? Suggest you use JSON.parse and try and access the resulting elements directly and then sort out the map function, once you are sure it is coming through correctly.